# Sudoku Game in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**Here is what I was instructed to do for this code:** 
basic implementation of a simple Sudoku “array”. The basic implementation will have a representation of the Sudoku puzzle and a way for the user to insert a value, remove a value, check a value for validity with current data along the row, column and within the box, and print the “array” with the values listed. The print function should indicate which values are not valid with the current data, but does not have to be a grid display (i.e. it can be just a horizontal list of the array items). Array items should be numbered such that the top leftmost element is arrayname[0,0], the top rightmost element is arrayname[0,8], the bottom leftmost element is arrayname[8,0] and the bottom rightmost element is arrayname[8,8].

The following methods are required:
Two constructors – one that initializes a completely empty grid, and another that initializes the grid to the values shown above under required features.

- `public void printMySudoku()` – prints the current values of the Sudoku array, including empty spots
- `public boolean insertVal(int r, int c, int val)` – returns true if able to insert the value indicated in val into the Sudoku array at the location indicated by r - row and c - column and inserts it.
- `public boolean removeVal(int r, int c, int val)` – returns true if able to remove the value indicated in val into the Sudoku array at the location indicated by r - row and c - column and removes it.
- `private boolean checkRow(int r, int c, int val)` – returns true if it is okay to insert val at location indicated by r - row and c - column along that ROW.
- `private boolean checkCol(int r, int c, int val)` – returns true if it is okay to insert val at location indicated by r - row and c - column along that COLUMN.
- `private boolean checkBox(int r, int c, int val)` – returns true if it is okay to insert val at location indicated by r - row and c - column inside that BOX.

**The only thing I have left to do is create a check that prints out a statement if the user inserts the row, column, or value 9 or over. I have tried multiple times to do this, but have failed. I'm a little hazy on where to put it, and need some help with the coding of the check. I have done my whole assignment by myself, and this is my personal code. I just need help with the check part.**

**Here is my code as of now (with no check in it):**

```
public class Sudoku {
    public int[][] grid;

    Sudoku(){
        grid = new int[9][9]; //empty
    }

    Sudoku(String start){  
        grid = new int[9][9];
        for(int x = 0; x <9; x++){
            for(int y =0; y<9; y++){
                grid[x][y] = 0;
            }
        }

        grid[0][0] = 5; //top left most
        grid[0][1] = 3;
        grid[0][4] = 7;
        grid[1][0] = 6;
        grid[1][3] = 1;
        grid[1][4] = 9;
        grid[1][5] = 5;
        grid[2][1] = 9;
        grid[2][2] = 8;
        grid[2][7] = 6;
        grid[3][0] = 8;
        grid[3][4] = 6;
        grid[3][8] = 3;
        grid[4][0] = 4;
        grid[4][3] = 8;
        grid[4][5] = 3;
        grid[4][8] = 1;
        grid[5][0] = 7;
        grid[5][4] = 2;
        grid[5][8] = 6;
        grid[6][1] = 6;
        grid[6][6] = 2;
        grid[6][7] = 8;
        grid[7][3] = 4;
        grid[7][4] = 1;
        grid[7][5] = 9;
        grid[7][8] = 5;
        grid[8][4] = 8;
        grid[8][7] = 7;
        grid[8][8] = 9; //bottom right most

    }

    public void printMySudoku(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                System.out.println(" -----------------------");
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
                if (j % 3 == 0) System.out.print("| ");
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] == 0
                        ? " "
                                : Integer.toString(grid[i][j]));

                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
        System.out.println(" -----------------------");
    }

    public boolean insertVal(int row, int col, int myVal){
        System.out.println("Entered insertVal " + "row " + row + "       column " + col + " myVal " + myVal);
        if(checkRow(row, col, myVal) == false) 
            return false;

        if(checkCol(row, col, myVal) == false)
            return false;

        if(checkBox(row, col, myVal) == false) 
            return false;

        grid[row][col] = myVal;


        return true;

    }

    public boolean removeVal(int row, int col, int myVal) {
        grid[row][col] = 0;

        return true;
    }

    private boolean checkRow(int row, int col, int myVal) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 9; ++a)  // row
            if (myVal == grid[row][a]){
                System.out.println(myVal + " Already in Row: " + row);
                return false;
            }
        return true;

    }
    private boolean checkCol(int row, int col, int myVal) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 9; ++b)  // column
            if (myVal == grid[b][col]){
                System.out.println(myVal + " Already in Column: " + col);  
                return false;
            }
        return true;

    }

    private boolean checkBox(int row, int col, int myVal) {
        int boxRowOffset = (row / 3)*3;
        int boxColOffset = (col / 3)*3;
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; ++c) // box
            for (int d = 0; d < 3; ++d)
                if (myVal == grid[boxRowOffset+c][boxColOffset+d]){
                    System.out.println(myVal + " Already in Box " );
                     return false;
                }
        return true;

    }
}
```

**Here is my Tester:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
   public class Play {


   public static void main(String args[]){

       Sudoku i = new Sudoku("start");
       i.printMySudoku();
       Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);

       int row, col, val;
       String action;

       while(true){
           System.out.println("Enter I for insert or R for remove: ");
           action = guess.next();

           System.out.println("Row: ");
           row = guess.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Column: ");
           col = guess.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Value: ");
           val = guess.nextInt();

           if(action.equals("I")){
               if(i.insertVal(row, col, val)){
                   System.out.println("Good Job  ");
               }
               else System.out.println("Try Again ");
               i.printMySudoku();
           }
           else{ i.removeVal(row, col, val);
           i.printMySudoku();}
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

```
int temp = 0;

// first, assign the guess to a temporary variable
if ((temp = guess.nextInt()) > 9) { // is this out of range?
    System.out.println("You can't do that, it's too big");
} else {
    // assign whichever one you're assigning, row/col/val to temp
}
```

I suggest using one of these blocks for each assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you include a specific method to do the validation:

```
private static int validate(int value)
{
    int validated;
    if (value<1 || value>9)
    {
        validated=-1;
        System.err.println("Error: Parameter must be between 1 and 9");
    }
    else
    {
        validated=value;
    }
    return validated;
}
```

... and then use it to validate every parameter read from the scanner, in this way:

```
do
{
    System.out.println("Row: ");
    row = validate(guess.nextInt());
}
while (row<0);
```

... same with parameters col and value (you can use the same validation method for them all).